# Problem using the index of a UITableView to change a String

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm fairly new to iPhone programming and I have a project that needs to be completed soon. I am trying to use a UITableView to list three websites and then load up to desired website on selection. This is the code I have so far:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

    if (storyIndex = 1) {
        venueLink = @"http://kos-mediadesign.com/Storage/IconVenues/IconVenue.html";
    }

    else if (storyIndex = 2) {
        venueLink = @"http://kos-mediadesign.com/Storage/IconVenues/SmythsVenue.html";
    }

    else if (storyIndex = 3) {
        venueLink = @"http://kos-mediadesign.com/Storage/IconVenues/SinnotsVenue.html";
    }
}
```

No matter what site I select the first one is always opened in my DetailView. I would really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks,
Kev

Comment: replace the "=" with "==". Then it will work. And for getting the row index, you can use "indexPath.row" in place of "[indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1]"

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an equal sign.

= is assigning Value

== is comparing

try

```
 int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

    if (storyIndex == 1) {
        venueLink = @"http://kos-mediadesign.com/Storage/IconVenues/IconVenue.html";
    }

    else if (storyIndex == 2) {
        venueLink = @"http://kos-mediadesign.com/Storage/IconVenues/SmythsVenue.html";
    }

    else if (storyIndex == 3) {
        venueLink = @"http://kos-mediadesign.com/Storage/IconVenues/SinnotsVenue.html";
    }
```

Comment: It happened to the best of us :)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if (storyIndex = 1) {
```

sets the value of storyIndex to 1.

This:

```
if (storyIndex == 1) {
```

tests whether the value of storyIndex is 1. Switch to double equals signs and your code will work.